# Microsoft Graph throwing NullReferenceException while Subscribing to Calendar notifications

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am encountering a weird problem with Microsoft Graph as this piece of code has been working fine for years in Production but it has recently started to break.

Microsoft Graph returns a NullReferenceException when I try to subscribe to a user's Calendar notifications.

I have tested this on an outlook.com email so far. I am using .NET Framework 4.8 and Microsoft.Graph v1.21.0.0.

Here's my code:

```
        public async Task<string> SubscribeToWebhookNotifications(string NewCalendarName)
    {
        var Client = await GetClientAsync();

        NewCalendarName = NewCalendarName ?? ExternalAppConfig.MICROSOFT_DEFAULT_CALENDAR;


        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(await GetCalendarID(NewCalendarName)))
        {
            throw new BusinessException("SubscribeToWebhookNotification", "MicrosoftApp", string.Format("Invalid calendar name provided. Calendar Name: {0}", NewCalendarName), Resource.Manage_SaveSyncConsent_Invalid_Calendar);
        }

        var subscription = new Microsoft.Graph.Subscription()
        {
            ChangeType = ExternalAppConfig.MICROSOFT_WEBHOOK_CHANGE_TYPES, // created, updated, deleted
            NotificationUrl = ExternalAppConfig.MICROSOFT_WEBHOOK_NOTIFICATION_URL,
            Resource = ExternalAppConfig.MICROSOFT_WEBHOOK_EVENT_RESOURCE,
            ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(4230),
            ClientState = ExternalAppConfig.MICROSOFT_WEBHOOK_SECRET_VALUE,
        };

        var data = await Client.Subscriptions
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(subscription); // This is the piece of code that throws a NullReferenceException 

        return data.Id;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that MS Graph throws a `NullReferenceException`. My guess is that the request result is `null` (type is `Subscription?`) and you are trying to access `Id` of `null`. Because you didn't change your code and it worked, I would check if the variables from `ExternalAppConfig` are valid or loaded correctly.

1. Do the variables from `ExternalAppConfig` are loaded correctly (non empty, non null)?
2. Has the url of your backend or your webhook validation route changed? This would be relevant for `MICROSOFT_WEBHOOK_NOTIFICATION_URL`.
3. Is the user that you are using still active (assuming you are not using the /me endpoint)? Relevant for `MICROSOFT_WEBHOOK_EVENT_RESOURCE`.

But the probability that this is the issue is quite low because then you would normally get an `ServiceException` (f.e. http status code 404 if user or calendar was not found).

---

What I just noticed is that you didn't post the message of the exception. So it could also be possible that `Client` or `ExternalAppConfig` is `null`.

Comment: Optimal - you are amazing! Thank you so much for your help! Turns out, the URL specified in MICROSOFT_WEBHOOK_NOTIFICATION_URL was an old invalid URL. I have updated it to a valid URL and it seems to be working. Thanks once again for your help!